# PHP Automated Wordpress Installer using shell_exec() speedup process

Tags: php, linux

I'm trying to make and automated installer for my platform that download lastest wordpress tar and untar directly in the member directory, then remove all the temp files.

```
<?php
$dir = $_GET['username'];
if ($dir != null ) {
   print 'Downloading...';
   shell_exec('wget https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz -P /home/ubuntu/workspace/members/' . $dir);
   sleep(10);
   print 'OK | ';
   print 'Extracting...';
   shell_exec('tar xvzf /home/ubuntu/workspace/members/' . $dir . '/lastest.tar.gz -C /home/ubuntu/workspace/members/' . $dir);
   sleep(20);
   print 'OK | ';
   print 'Moving to root...';
   shell_exec('mv /home/ubuntu/workspace/members/' . $dir . '/wordpress /home/ubuntu/workspace/members/' . $dir);
   sleep(20);
   print 'OK | ';
   print 'Directory polish...';
   shell_exec('rm /home/ubuntu/workspace/members/' .$dir . '/wordpress | rm /home/ubuntu/workspace/members' . $dir . '/lastest.tar.gz');
   print 'OK | DONE.';
} else {
   print 'Error in get member name';
}
```

This work fine, latest file where downloaded and extracted, files where moved etc.

I would like to speedup the execution of this script, i've put the `sleep()`to make sure commands are not executed after the previous is done but I don't know if the system is loaded so I've put much time to wait.

There is a way to exactly know when a process is complete and start next process? will I must to put all in a line using the command separator `|`? Or there is an easy way to make it faster?

**EDIT:** According to the Replies it's easy to make this working faster removing the `sleep()`commands, but this script is pretty unsecure, so how can I make this more secure to execute?

Comment: as far as i know, and the manual says, [shell_exec](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) returns the *whole* output string. to do so, it must wait for the *command to complete* before returning something. meaning: you do not need to `sleep` **at all**. that being said, the way you use a GET-parameter directly on a command line is a **huge security risk** which could compromise your server in mere seconds. imagine something like `;rm -rf /` being transmitted and enjoy your lost data.

Comment: thanks, I've not tried to make it working without `sleep` command. That's my fault and I'm feeling little stupid. If you post as a reply I will make as replied

Comment: The script is executed by an ajax request, is there a way the command can be hijacked?

Comment: by an attacker simply typing the url manually. **never trust user input**

Comment: Thanks a lot, how can I make more secure this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[shell_exec](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)** does not return until the executing command is complete - which you can verify yourself by running

```
<?php
shell_exec("sleep 3");
echo "done";
```

and seeing how long it takes.

Meaning: you **do not have to sleep** at all.

That being said: using user input directly in a system command is a **huge huge** security risk. any attacker could inject malicious code and completely compromise your server without lots of effort. a complete loss of data would be the least threatening scenario.

As a baseline: **never trust user input!**. to make your current code more secure: verify the input - for example, check if it is only alphanumeric, if it's a valid username, if it's the name of the currently logged in user, if the folder actually exists, and so on.
Best would be to store a sanitized path to your user directory in a database and look it up (with parameterized statements, lest you open yourself to SQL Injection instead).

Comment: There is no user input here, the `$_GET` that will be `$_POST`when I've finished to test will be sent by an ajax call and taken from login session.

Comment: $_GET and $_POST come from outside the server, so they **are user input**. data inside them is **not** to be trusted. **anybody** can forge the ajax call with arbitrary values. it's easiest for GET: just type in the URL manually.

Comment: thanks I will try to find another way to do this, maybe with an `sh` script?